# “Itis” Versus “Is” in Latin

Tags: verbs, morphology, conjugation, duolingo

I am learning Latin on Duolingo, and the app does not clarify when to use “itis” and when to use “is”. They both mean “to go”, for the second person singular in present tense. Clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *itis* is the second person **plural** (present active indicative). Generally, *-s* is the regular active second person singular ending, and *-tis* the plural (except for the perfect tense). Mind you, *ire* is an irregular verb -- pretty rare in Latin! -- but these two forms happen to be regular.

By the way, in case of such questions, Wiktionary offers complete conjugation tables for all Latin verbs that it lists: See their entry for [*eo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eo#Latin). (Didn't know you had to look up *eo*? Wiktionary has you covered, [*itis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/itis#Latin) links to it.) In my experience, the tables on Wiktionary are high quality and definitely less error-prone than those on certain other, ad-riddled websites.

Comment: One can also use Perseus' [Morphological tool](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph) to quickly see the available grammatical options.

Comment: I also find [latin-english.com](https://www.latin-english.com/) useful when I have a conjugation or declension and I'm not sure what the dictionary entry is. It was made by a member of the site. I don't recall which dictionary it searches, though. For reference, [here is what you get](https://www.latin-english.com/latin/itis/) when you search for _itis_.